# How to install gnome-tweak-tool in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, 17.10

I am unable to install `gnome-tweak-tool` in Ubuntu 17.10

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gnome-tweak-tool is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnome-tweak-tool' has no installation candidate
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You wrote 17.10 in the title, added [14.04] & [ubuntu-gnome] tags. All cannot be correct at once.

Comment: For sure the 14.04 tag is not right here, since its clearyl been talked bout 17.10. Replacing it now with 17.10 tag.

Comment: Make sure `ubuntu-artful-universe` *aka. `universe`) is avaliable.